# Simple Wordpress (PHP) Array access. How to get a value out of an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm new to PHP and am attempting to hack together a Wordpress theme. This is the first time I have come across arrays in PHP and dont know how to use them...

I have the following line of code:

```
photo url: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'member-photo', true);?>
```

Which instead of displaying the url of a file I uploaded into a wordpress record using the custom-field member-photo just displays "Array".

You can see this if you view http://ebf.websiteinprogress.co.uk/members/scott-griffiths/

I now understand that the URL I need is stored in an Array, but don tknow how to modify my code to access this value.

What I actually want to achieve is to render an image using this value, so the ultimate code I require would do this:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'member-photo', true)):?><p><span itemprop="photo"><img src="***URL-TO-GO-HERE***" alt="<?php the_title()?>" title="<?php the_title()?>" width="200"></span></p><?php endif;?>
```

Your assistance most appreicated.
I need the code to add to the page to make this work, not an explanation of how to do it 'cos i'm not that talented at PHP i'm afraid. I'm an SEO trying to make something work!

Comment: have you tried `print_r(get_post_meta($post->I[...])` ? That way you can see what is in the array.

Comment: `echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'member-photo', true);` should be a string, so makes me think there is an issue elsewhere. Make sure `$post->ID` and `member-photo` are correct. e.g. `print_r($post->ID)` and double check you have the right meta key.

Answer (score 0):

get_post_meta always returns an array. The item you want is the first element so all you have to do is:
photo url: ID, 'member-photo', true)[0];?>

also a better way to view an array for debug purposes is var_dump(variable);

Comment: According to the documentation, `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'member-photo', true)` should return a string. `If $single is set to true, the function returns the first value of the specified key (not in an array) `. [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)